# Feature extraction for keyword spotting on long form audio using a CNN

Tags: python, keras, speech-recognition, librosa

I've built a simple CNN word detector that is accurately able to predict a given word when using a 1-second .wav as input. As seems to be the standard, I'm using the MFCC of the audio files as input for the CNN.

However, my goal is to be able to apply this to longer audio files with multiple words being spoken, and to have the model be able to predict if and when a given word is spoken. I've been searching online how the best approach, but seem to be hitting a wall and I truly apologize if the answer could've been easily found through google.

My first thought is to cut the audio file into several windows of 1-second length that intersect each other -

[image: a busy cat]

and then convert each window into an MFCC and use these as input for the model prediction.

My second thought would be to instead use onset detection in attempts isolate each word, add padding if the word if it was < 1-second, and then feed these as input for the model prediction.

Am I way off here? Any references or recommendations would hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cutting the audio up into analysis windows is the way to go.  It is common to use some overlap. The MFCC features can be calculated first and then split done using an integer number of frames that gets you closest to the window length you want (1s).

See [How to use a context window to segment a whole log Mel-spectrogram (ensuring the same number of segments for all the audios)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260929/how-to-use-a-context-window-to-segment-a-whole-log-mel-spectrogram-ensuring-the) for example code